# Cannot read lines from a file using bash read command

Tags: bash

Created a text file as hello_world.rtf with following two lines only:
Hello
World

and trying to read above file using below bash script from terminal:

```
while test= read -r line; do
> echo "The text read from file is: $line"
> done < hello_world.rtf
```

and it returns the following:

```
The text read from file is: {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf500
The text read from file is: {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
The text read from file is: {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
The text read from file is: {\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
The text read from file is: \paperw12240\paperh15840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
The text read from file is: \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0
The text read from file is: 
The text read from file is: \f0\fs24 \cf0 Hello\
```

Any suggestion what is wrong here and how can I get the clean result?

Comment: [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) means Rich Text Format. It is a language for text formatting (developed and used mostly by Microsoft and deprecated for a while). The text inside the file looks as you can see in the output of your code. It contains the words _"Hello"_ and _"World"_ but also formatting instructions. Save the file as plain text, not RTF and it will contain only the text you typed in it.

Comment: `test=` in front of `read` does not have any effect.

Comment: Thank you @axiac, I removed "test=" and changed the file as txt file and now it returns only one line i.e. The text read from file is: Hello. I am expecting a similar line for "World" also.

Comment: Make sure the second line ends with a new-line character. `read` returns `false` when reaches the end of file and your code exits the `while` loop and does not display the last value read by `read`. If the file ends with a new-line character, the last line (that is read but not listed by the code) is empty, therefore nothing is lost. It is a recommended practice for text files to always end with a newline character. Alternatively you can print the value of `line` again after the loop.

Comment: Super!!! it works like a charm now. Thank you so much @axiac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) means Rich Text Format. It is a language for text formatting, developed and used mostly by Microsoft and deprecated for a while.

The text inside the file looks as you can see in the output of your code. It contains the words *"Hello"* and *"World"* but also formatting instructions.

Save the file as plain text, not RTF and it will contain only the text you typed in it.

`test=` in front of `read` does not have any effect in this context. You can remove it.

Make sure the last line of the file ends with a new-line character. [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) returns an non-zero exit status (and this means `false`) when it reaches the end of file and your code exits the `while` loop and does not display the last value read by `read`. If the file ends with a new-line character, the last line (that is read but not listed by the code) is empty, therefore nothing is lost.

It is a recommended practice for text files to always end with a [newline character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

---

Alternatively you can print the value of `line` again after the loop. It contains the last line of the file (from the last end-of-line character until the end of file).